# Sharepoint page menu items gone?

Tags: sharepoint, menu, sharepoint-2007

I'm running MOSS 2007 and have created a new site under an existing one using sitemanager.aspx. I've done this on two machines. The permissions on both sites should be the same. On one of those everything works correctly, while on the other some of the menu items for pages in the site seem to be gone. Also on the faulty site I get "Access denied" when I click "Version history".

Comment: Excuse the double question, miss on paste...

Comment: On the original site of the faulty machine, do you have permission problems too? When creating a subsite, you are inheriting the permissions of the parent unless you specify not to, thus if you have permission problems on the parent, they will be there on the subsite too.

Comment: Are both servers patched to the same point and running the same versions of everything?

Comment: The most obvious cause of this would be permissions. Are you a site Collection administrator for the site on both machines?

Comment: Paul, i wanned to write that as an answer, but it's yours, i don't want to steal your reputation. It's ofcourse obvious that the logged in user does not have such permissions like check-in/check-out, edit and such if environment doesn't have some features that hides those actions.

Comment: The servers are patched to the same point. Seems to be some kind of permission issue, I'm not sure which though.
Is there any way to check active permissions on a particular object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a known issue that was fixed in the cumulative update from Feb 2009.

In short the RenderXMLUsingPattern attribute on a Field definition gets lost and has to be set back to TRUE.

[A tool to fix this issue](http://blog.ginzburgconsulting.com/get-back-your-sharepoint-2007-site-manager-context-menu/).

[Blog entry about the issue including solution](http://odole.wordpress.com/2009/01/30/access-denied-error-message-while-editing-properties-of-any-document-in-a-moss-document-library/)